# How to make a WordPress page template responsive?

Tags: html, wordpress, responsive

I have a wordpress website that uses hestia theme. I have added some custom page templates. How to make them responsive ?
In one of these pages I have 2 tables that align side by side to the right and when I change the size of the screen on their bottom borders do not match.

This is the code :

```
<div class="div2" id="profile" style="display: none;">
        <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)):?>
        <h1 style="text-align:center">Volunteer's Profile</h1>
        <h2 style="text-align:center"> Welcome, <?php  
        echo $row['fname']; 
        ?> !</h2>
        <br>
        
         <table class="pro" style="float:left;width:20%;">
         
               
                
                    <tr class="inpro"><th>ID</th></tr>
                    <tr class="inpro"><th>First name</th></tr>
                    <tr class="inpro"><th>Last Name</th></tr>
                    <tr class="inpro"><th>Phone</th></tr>
                    <tr class="inpro"><th>Email</th></tr>
                    <tr class="inpro"><th>DOB</th></tr>
                    <tr class="inpro"><th>City</th></tr>
                    <tr class="inpro"><th>Degree</th></tr>
                    <tr class="inpro"><th>Major</th></tr>
                    <tr class="inpro"><th>Volunteering type</th></tr>
                    <tr class="inpro"><th>Achieved hours</th></tr>
                    <tr class="inpro"><th>Membership</th></tr>
                    <tr class="inpro"><th>Points</th></tr>
                    <tr class="inpro"><th>Rating</th></tr>
                    <tr class="inpro"><th>Warnings</th></tr>
                    
                    </table>
                    
                    <table class="pro" style="float:left;width:30%">
                

               
                    <tr class="inpro2"><td><?php echo $row['id'];?></td></tr>
                    <tr class="inpro2"><td><?php echo $row['fname'];?></td></tr>
                    <tr class="inpro2"><td><?php echo $row['lname'];?></td></tr>
                    <tr class="inpro2"><td><?php echo $row['phone'];?></td></tr>
                    <tr class="inpro2"><td><?php echo $row['email'];?></td></tr>
                    <tr class="inpro2"><td><?php echo $row['DOB'];?></td></tr>
                    <tr class="inpro2"><td><?php echo $row['city'];?></td></tr>
                    <tr class="inpro2"><td><?php echo $row['degree'];?></td></tr>
                    <tr class="inpro2"><td><?php echo $row['major'];?></td></tr>
                    <tr class="inpro2"><td><?php echo $row['Vtype'];?></td></tr>
                    <tr class="inpro2"><td><?php echo $row['hours'];?></td></tr>
                    <tr class="inpro2"><td><?php echo $row['membership'];?></td></tr>
                    <tr class="inpro2"><td><?php echo $row['points'];?></td></tr>
                    <tr class="inpro2"><td><?php echo $row['rating'];?></td></tr>
                    <tr class="inpro2"><td><?php echo $row['warnings'];?></td></tr>
                
               <?php endwhile;?>
            </table>
```

Also I included the meta viewport in the head section as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
    <head>
        
        <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
```

Comment: sorry, the tables align to the left not to the right

Comment: Looking at that theme it uses Bootstrap v1 (which is super old) ... that being said you could review [Bootstrap grid](https://getbootstrap.com/1.1.1/#grid-system) to get an idea how to make your grids. Along with the tables as found on the documentation. This isn't really a PHP question it's CSS